# css issue with the image on internet explorer 7

Tags: css

```
.plus input[type="submit"] 
{
background: url("../Image/button_one.png") no-repeat;
border: medium none;
float: right;
height: 32px;
margin-right: 14px;
margin-top: 53px;
width: 32px;
}
```

I m using following code to display the button on the image it works with all browsers but when it comes to internet explorer 7 the button get out from the image.

Comment: can you post a Demo with HTML and CSS.

Comment: <div class="plus">
<input type="submit" name=""  value="" />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

`input[type="submit"]` doesn't support by IE 7 and IE8 **[see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%5Btype=%22submit%22%5D)**. IT would be good to make a class.

Also you are writing a  css in wrong manner. It should be like this. A working **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kosituhu/3/edit)**.

```
 input.plus[type="submit"] 
{
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/60/30/") 0 0 no-repeat;
height: 32px;
width: auto;
}
input[type="submit"] 
{border:1px solid black;
width: 132px;}
```

Comment: i agree but the button next to it is on the image with the same code i showed above.

Comment: ofcourse it will appear because you are wrapping your input field inside a div and giving a class name `plus`.

Comment: the button css will conflict if i use input[type="submit"]  because i have to use same buttons on the whole psd. input[type="submit"]  this code will we same for all buttons...

Comment: then my suggestion will work for you. I've used class `plus` and that used for one input button. If you don't want to apply a image for other button then you no need to add class name `plus` in input field.